# Extracting required text

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe contains information on different US states, and a sample looks like this:

```
Region ID    Region Name
1112233      New York, NY
4445556      Carroll, IA
```

The dataframe contains 50 columns like this. How can I create a new dataframe that contains Region Names that have IL and IA only after the comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to get those rows whose region names end with IA or IL after comma:

```
df2 = df[df['Region Name'].apply(lambda region_name : region_name.endswith(', IL') or region_name.endswith(', IA'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` or `str.extract()`. For example:

```
df['Region_Abr'] = df['Region Name'].str.extract(', (.+)$')[0]
```

Or:

```
df['Region_Abr'] = df['Region Name'].str.split(', ').str[-1]
```

Output:

```
   Region ID   Region Name Region_Abr
0    1112233  New York, NY         NY
1    4445556   Carroll, IA         IA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
df['RegAb']=df['Region Name'].str.extract('((?<=\,\s)[A-Z]+)')
```

or still

```
df['RegAb']=df['Region Name'].str.split(',').str[-1]

Region ID    Region Name    RegAb
0   1112233  New York, NY   NY
1   4445556  Carroll, IA    IA
```